# Infinite Loop - WP_Query

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

I am struggling to work out why the below code would cause an infinite loop, any pointers would be brilliant.

```
function send_reminder_email() {    
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'product',
        'meta_key'      => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
        'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
      'order'           => 'ASC',       
        'meta_query'    => array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'WooCommerceEventsDate',
                    'value'   => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days')),
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if($query->have_posts()) : 
        while($query->have_posts()) : 
            $query->the_post();     

            $event[] = array( "title" => get_the_title(), "id" => get_the_ID());

        endwhile;           
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();

    print_r($event);


    foreach($event as $key => $value): 

        $args = array(
            'post_type'  => 'event_magic_tickets',
            'meta_key'   => 'WooCommerceEventsProductID',
            'post_status'=> 'publish',          
            'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key'     => 'WooCommerceEventsProductID',
                        'value'   => $value['id'],
                        'compare' => '=',
                    ),
            ),
        );

        $ticketQuery = new WP_Query( $args );       

        if($ticketQuery->have_posts()) : 

            while($ticketQuery->have_posts()): 
                echo "Do something here.";                      
            endwhile;   

        endif;
        wp_reset_query();
    endforeach;         

}
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. Knew it was something simple. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop, the `$ticketQuery` loop is missing `$ticketQuery->the_post()`.

The function `the_post()` actually sets up things like template tags, the `$post` object. The most important thing it does is increments the post counter so that eventually `$ticketQuery->have_posts()` will eventually return false. Without `the_post()` is your infinite loop.